# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Angular + Angular Material 2 (SSR doesn't work)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material2, asp.net-core-2.0, server-side-rendering

I have created [asp.net core Angular template project](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) in Visual studio 2017.
I added and configured [Angular Material 2](https://material.angular.io/).

But when a page loads, I see a common html button. But after loading all js files, styles are applied to the button.

1) Page is loading:
[image: Page is loading]
2) Page is loaded
[image: Page is loaded]

Also I have created **GIF**: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cubyt536g2hvxqn/asp.ner%20core%20material%20ssr%20bug.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got an [Official answer (2/21/2018)](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1535#issuecomment-367276464)